# Best massive data persistent storage with TTL?

Tags: java, mongodb, architecture, cassandra, persistence

We are building a system which needs to put tons of data into some persistent storage for a fixed amount of time - 30 to 60 days. Since the data is not critical (we can lose some for example when virtual machine goes down) and we don't want to pay the price of persisting it with every request (latency is critical for us) we were thinking about either buffering & batching the data or sending in an async manner.

Data is append only, we would need to persist 2-3 items per request, system processes ~10k rps on multiple hosts scaled horizontally.

We are hesitating between choosing Mongo (3.x?) or Cassandra, but we can go with any other solution. Does anyone here have any experience or hints in solving this kind of problem? We are running some PoCs, but we might not be able to find all the problems early enough and pivot might be costly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment on MongoDB but I can talk to Cassandra. Cassandra does indeed have a TTL feature in which you can expire data after a certain time. You have to plan for it though because TTL's do add some overhead during a process Cassandra runs called 'compaction' - see: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_write_path_c.html

and: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_expire_c.html

As long as you size for that kind of workload, you should be OK. That being said, Cassandra really excels when you have event driven data - things like time series, product catalogs, click stream data, ETC.

If you aren't familiar with Patrick McFadin, meet your new best friend: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tg6eIht-00M

And of course, the plenty of free tutorials and training here: https://academy.datastax.com/

EDIT to add one more idea of expiring data 'safely' and with the least overhead. This is one done by a sharp guy by the name of Ryan Svihla https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/10/20/domain-modeling-around-deletes-or-using-cassandra-as-a-queue-even-when-you-know-better/

Comment: Thanks, we actually mixed in ElastiSearch, as we probably will have to create some queries that use arbitrary fields, but your answer was very helpful.